# How can I do async-await operations in sequential order?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, react-cookie

I want to save the token in the cookie and run the navigation ("/"). In "/", it is implemented so that the token value is implemented.
Therefore, I want to use setCookie to run navigate after the token value comes in. I think we should use async await, so we tried a lot, but we failed.(I'm using the react-cookie library.)

```
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies("token");
axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/normal_login/`, formData)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data) {
   
          console.log(response.data.account_token);
          setCookie("token", response.data.account_token, {
            path: "/",
          });
          console.log("cookies", cookies);
          // navigate("/");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("==>", err);
 
      });
```

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
```

Comment: You could do with `async`/`await`, sure, but right now as it stands, `setCookie` is only ever called after the request finishes and the condition is meet. The code, in that way, looks correct to me.

Comment: An error occurs in the code above. I think it's because we went over to navigate ("/") before "token" was created with setCookie.

Comment: You have an unhandled error. You should add a `.catch` after the `.then` It seems there is an issue with your api call since it returns [401 Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401)

Comment: The error message is an error message received from .catch.
When I took the console.log() `setCookie("token", response.data.account_token, {
path: "/",
});
navigate("/");` When annotated, the response.data value could be returned from .then normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
async method(){
   const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies("token");
 try{
    var response= await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/normal_login/`, formData);
    if (response.data) {
       console.log(response.data.account_token);
       setCookie("token", response.data.account_token, {
       path: "/",
       });
       console.log("cookies", cookies);
          // navigate("/");
       }
  }
 catch(e){
   console.log(e);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `useEffect` with `cookie` as a dependencie to trigger something after the cookie changes. Something like:

```js
useEffect(() => navigate('/'), [cookies]);
```

Adding the dependencie to the useEffect make it act only when the variable (here `cookie`) in the dependencie is modified.

Comment: I've tried this method, but I have to refresh to move on.